# ¿Como usar el parametro REST?

Tags: javascript, html5, web

tengo una consulta, ¿De que manera puedo usar parametros **REST**? La unica forma que he visto en ejemplos y turoriales es la siguiente:

```js
function palabras(...entradas) {
 console.log("Estas son las palabras: ", entradas)
}
palabras("uno", "dos", "tres");
```

pero el problema que veo/tengo con este tipo de ejemplos es que no se esta usando una entrada "real" de datos, quisiera saber, ¿De que forma se suelen usar ese tipo de parametros? ¿Hay alguna forma de ingresarle datos en "tiempo real"? pense que con un **PROMPT** podria, pero directamente con este no se podría

Answer (score 4):

Cuando sabes exactamente cuántos parámetros va a recibir una función puede parecer un poco tonto el uso del operador *Rest*, pero tiene algunas ventajas que no son obvias. Por ejemplo, te permite saber cuántos parámetros estás recibiendo y trabajar con ellos más fácilmente. Antes de que existiese esta sintaxis la única opción era trabajar con el valor del parámetro *intrínseco* `arguments`:

```js
function f(a,b,c) {
  console.log('"a" vale', a);
  console.log('"b" vale', b);
  console.log('"c" vale', c);
  console.log('El número de parámetros recibidos es', arguments.length);
}

f(1)
f(1,undefined,undefined)
```

Pero este objeto `arguments` no es realmente un Array:

```js
function f(...params) {
 let sumaCuadrados=params.map(p => p ** 2).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
 console.log(sumaCuadrados);
}

f(1)
f(1,2,3)

function f2() {
 let sumaCuadrados=arguments.map(p => p ** 2).reduce((a,b) => a+b,0);
 console.log(sumaCuadrados);
}

f2(1,2,3) // arguments no es un Array, no tiene map, forEach o reduce
```

Y no siempre quieres todos los parámetros en el array:

```js
function potencias(exponente, ...bases) {
   return bases.map(b => b**exponente);
}

console.log(potencias(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Sin olvidarnos de un detalle importante: en las funciones flechas ¡no tenemos el objeto  `arguments`!

```js
let func= (...p) => {
  console.log('Parámetros:', p.length);
  console.log(arguments.length);
};

func(1,2,3,'a');
```

Entonces, tenemos escenarios en los que no sabemos en tiempo de compilación el número de parámetros? No del todo (olvidémonos de `eval()`, por favor), pero vamos verlo:

```js
function meta(delay, callback, ...params) {
   setTimeout(() => callback.apply(null,params),delay);
}

function callback1(p1) {
  
  console.log('He recibido el parámetro',p1);
}

function callback2(p1, p2) {
  
  console.log('He recibido el parámetro',p1, 'y también',p2);
}


const num = +prompt('Escribe un número');

if (num > 5) {
  meta(num * 100, callback1,1);
} else {
  meta(num *1000, callback2,1,2);
}
```

Podemos tener una función como `meta`, que según ciertas condiciones se llame con más o menos parámetros. No sabemos qué condición se cumplirá, pero sabemos que será una de las dos definidas.

Comment: Gracias, entonces no suele tener un uso tan comun, ¿verdad? ¿Y su uso no suele ser tan directo como lo explican(asi como "cree una funcion, ponga el parametro rest, ingrese los valores y llenemoslo como si fuera un array")?

Comment: Realmente sí es así de directo, y puede ser útil para simplificar el código, pero en general no aporta nada que no se pudiera hacer antes de su existencia.

Answer (score 3):

Es un poco difícil decir para todas las cosas que te puede servir, yo suelo utilizarlo para formar objetos o modificarlos.

Hay miles de aplicaciones, y llegará un momento en que estés formando un array o objeto de una manera, y podrás aplicar el parámetro REST, ya que no solamente es para deconstruir si no también para construir.

Aquí dejo un pequeño ejemplo de algo que se puede hacer:

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpzawuyd/)

En este ejemplo verás como puedes ir formando un objeto y modificar los valores de este con un código bastante sencillo gracias al parametro REST.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por el ejemplo, aunque segun pareciera en este caso tampoco aceptaria multiples entradas hacia el array, sino, de 1 en 1