# ¿Cómo utilizar los valores de un objeto como parámetros en otra función?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un objeto de tipo:

```
obj ={
  'key1': 'value1'
  'key2': 'value2'
  ...
  'keyN': 'valueN'
}
```

Esta función que hace una llamada ajax:

```
function fn(value1, value2 ... valueN){
    //esta funcion recibira los valores del objeto como parametro y en esta los utilizo
}
```

Luego tengo una función que recibe parámetros.. la función y el objeto anterior y otro valor:

```
function asignObjValues(fn, object, value){
    object[value] = 'algo'
    fn(Object.values(object));  //si lo hago asi lo estoy pasando los valores del objeto en un arreglo

   //quiero pasarlos de la forma fn('algo', 'value2', 'valueN')

}

asignObjValues(fn, obj, 'key1')
```

¿Cómo hago para pasar los valores de mi objeto como parámetros de mi otra función y no como un arreglo..?

Comment: Pero es que fn siempre va a recibir los parámetros como un arreglo, porque la has definido con un rest parameter. Es decir, por mucho que cambies la invocación, por definición dentro de la función siempre va a tener un arreglo, porque es en lo que consiste "...objValues", en que permite enviar cualquier número de parámetros a una función como un arreglo. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245846/como-usar-el-parametro-rest/

Comment: @S.Bonet Sí, esa parte de la pregunta no queda muy clara

Comment: @S.Bonet hola lo puse asi mas bien como pseudocodigo.. pueden ser una cantidad n de parametros.. lo cambio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply):

```js
function fn( param1, param2, param3) {
   console.log(param1, param2, param3);
}

fn('Hola',3,{});

const params = ['p1',2,'p3'];

//el primer parámetro de apply es el contexto, el valor que tendrá "this"
fn.apply(null,params);
```

Y si no tienes que preocuparte de Internet Explorer, puedes usar el *operador Spread*:

```js
function fn( param1, param2, param3) {
   console.log('Param1:',param1,'Param2:', param2,'Param3:', param3);
}

fn('Hola',3,{});

const params = ['p1',2,'p3'];

fn(...params)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Pablo.. menos mal quie siempre estas por ahi.. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Si entendí lo que buscas, solo deberías agregar `...` ([sintáxis spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread)) cuando llamas a la función.

```js
const obj ={'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2','keyN': 'valueN'}

function fn(valor1, valor2, valor3) {
  console.log(valor1);
  console.log(valor2);
  console.log(valor3);
}

fn(...Object.values(obj)); //<-- Lo mismo que fn(value1, value2, valueN)
```

Si no podemos definir la cantidad de argumentos en la función, podemos usar [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments):

```js
const obj ={'key1': 'value1','key2': 'value2','keyN': 'valueN'}

function fn() {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
}

fn(...Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: En lugar de usar arguments se puede declarar la función como `fn(...args) { ...}`. Viene a ser el efecto opuesto: al llamarla como `fn(a,b,c)` tendrías un array en args como estos tres parámetros. Es útil en funciones *flecha* donde arguments no existe

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respueta Emeeus asi lo encuentro muy practico... solo esta el tema de IE. Saludos